# What is the combination problem for panpsychism?

Tags: consciousness, information, david-chalmers, william-james, panpsychism

If consciousness at a fundamental level can combine to form other, more complicated conscious minds, then how does this occur? This was first posed by William James in 1890 in The principles of Psychology. This was codified by William Seager in 1995 in Consciousness, Information, and Panpsychism, and further explored by David Chalmers in 2016 in The Combination Problem for Panpsychism.

Comment: You seem to have answered your own question. The combination problem is as you describe it. We don't know how combination could occur.

Comment: I, too, fail to see the *question* here when the most important texts for an *answer* and what they contribute are already in the body of the question.

Comment: @MarcoOcram: But defenders of Pansychism must seek to defend answers. Surely that's the question..?

Comment: @CriglCragl you could well be right, but that's not how the question currently reads. If it had been edited to something like 'How do defenders of Pansychism address the combination problem?' I wouldn't have made my comment.

Comment: Aside from [SEP](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/panpsychism/#CombProb), from which, I assume, the OP description is taken, [PhilPapers](https://philpapers.org/browse/the-combination-problem-for-panpsychism) has a summary of the combination problem that includes several recent references. [SEP's Possible Solutions to the Subject-Summing Problem](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/panpsychism/supplement.html) surveys proposed solutions to one aspect of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"...even if we do attribute basic consciousness to the smallest bits of the brain, it’s still not clear how to intelligibly account for the consciousness of the brain as a whole. How do the interactions of trillions of tiny minds produce a big mind? This is the so-called “combination problem” for panpsychism..."
Philip Goff

Of course what I will say does not constitute an answer to how, but points to an equivalent phenomenon in nature.

The magnet: A magnet is not a magnet because of the way the material is constructed, but because it was exposed to a magnetic field; which means that magnetism is a qualitative property of the material. The same material that wasn't a magnet can become a magnet. By adding two magnets you get a bigger one. By dividing a magnet you get two of them.

Comment: We can explain this for magnets, but not for consciousness. An analogy is not a proper theory.

Comment: Sure, it's not a theory, just food for thought.

Comment: Sorry, that's not how StackExchange works. Things should only be posted as an answer if they *actually answer the question*, if partially. This here is a tangential thought of you, not even based in some supporting sources. It should be a comment, if posted at all.

Comment: Ok, I didn't know, but keep in mind that magnetism in its natural form is not explained, see https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bohr%E2%80%93Van_Leeuwen_theorem

Comment: You may want to read the [help center on how to answer](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer). Mind, StackExchange is not a forum in the classical sense, its original idea is about "*Experts* answering your questions". Hence, even if I admit that it is hard to see at times, there are different standards for both questions and answers in place.

Comment: I read the "how to answer" and I conclude that what I wrote constitutes a valid answer, but anyway thanks for the advise.

Comment: I think the point is that magnetism is precisely not an 'equivalent phenomenon' as consciousness. As far as we know, joining two brains does not make  one bigger consciousness, and cutting one in half does not make two smaller ones.

Comment: "...even if we do attribute basic consciousness to the smallest bits of the brain, it’s still not clear how to intelligibly account for the consciousness of the brain as a whole. How do the interactions of trillions of tiny minds produce a big mind? This is the so-called “combination problem” for panpsychism..." Philip Goff

Answer (score 0):

There is an assumption that proto-consciousness combines to form higher levels of consciousness. If this is not so then there is no combination problem.